# Multiple React + Redux functions in HTML event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, dom-events

The general behavior that I want is on an event, update a property in the Redux state tree, and then access the updated property, right after the state tree has been updated.

But below, what happens is the `synchronousReducer` function makes it's call, and then the `relevantProperty` is undefined. Everything is re-rendered, and only then is `relevantProperty` updated.

How should I accomplish this goal the Redux way? No anti-patterns please.

```
const { relevantProperty } = props;
...
<button onClick={() =>
  synchronousReducer(); // This updates relevantProperty in the Redux state tree.
  console.log(relevantProperty); // undefined 
  loadEvent(relevantProperty);
  
} />
```

Comment: try synchronousReducer().then(() => console.log(releventProperty));

Comment: When I do this I just receive an error that synchronousReducer().then(...) is not a function.

Comment: More context on *why* you need to have immediate access the `relavantProperty` is needed in order to help.  The fact that you need multiple actions to occur (or multiple reducing operations) doesn't change the fact that the button was clicked once.  Why not just handle the button click action in 2 different ways?

Comment: Basically, synchronousReducer() is finding a next item in an array, and that next item, becomes the relevantProperty. Then that relevant property is loaded. I'm generalizing some details here, but the primary question for me, is given these constraints, can I use Redux in this way?

Comment: You have a syntax issue. Wrap the function code with `{}`